# Cannot Install app on phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am having trouble installing my app on my phone. It's the first time I run into this and it has probably to do with [using my own keystore to sign the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765911/default-debug-keystore-not-signing-in). I get this error window.

```
Installation failed since the device possibly has stale dexed jars that don't match the current version (dexopt error).
In order to proceed, you have to uninstall the existing application.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

If I choose to uninstall I get another error `DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR` and I cannot find my app anymore on my phone.

Before I got the error I was testing my app. As desktop it was perfect but on my phone there where massive graphical glitches. Might have to do something with that.

As you can see from my other post about the keystore I finally made some progress connecting to Play Services and now this strange error occurs. I cannot believe that I am running into another new error now, I spent multiple days to get my debug run connected to google.

Comment: The app might be installed for more than one user so go to settings--> app--> and check, the app may be remain here ...if yes remove it, hope will solve your problem..

Comment: @Prashant I checked if my app was there actually. It isn't however.

Comment: @Prashant I tried to clean the project. Build failed, it could not delete the debug folder. So I did that myself and I could clean the project. Now it works again. I'm still curious what this stale dexed jar error is. I do not have more then 64K methods, so what could cause it?

Comment: It might be because of error in your resources(xml) file. IDE can't build it properly or there might be some IDE problem...